# How do I make an object returned by the browser globally available then set a function as a property?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I am trying to access MIDI inputs in a ClojureScript project, using something like, in JS:

```
if (navigator.requestMIDIAccess) {
 console.log('WebMIDI is supported in this browser.');
 navigator.requestMIDIAccess().then(onMIDISuccess, onMIDIFailure);
```

I figured out how to get this to work with the Promesa library do! capability... however, the returned object, in JS, has a list of MIDI inputs, and one needs to set a function as the value of the 'onmidimessage' property of the inputs you care about. In JS this would look like this:

```
function onMIDISuccess(midiAccess) {
  var inputs = midiAccess.inputs;
  for (var input of midiAccess.inputs.values()) {
  input.onmidimessage = getMIDIMessage;
 }}
```

In JS, getMIDIMessage will be called whenever a MIDI message comes in. How do I set a function as the value of the 'onmidimessage' property of the return value of navigator.requestMIDIAccess so that it will be called properly?

I tried variations of set! and aget and neither work. Perhaps I'm incorrectly or not setting the 'midiAccess' object globally... not sure.

UPDATE: overcame embarrassment and added my attempt:

```
  (ns miditest.midi)

  (defn onMIDISuccess [midiAccess]
    (let [inputs (.values (.-inputs midiAccess))]
    (js/console.log (first inputs))))

  (defn onMIDIFailure []
    (js/console.log "this browser does not support WebMIDI."))

  (defn getMIDIMessage [message]
    (let [command (first (.data message))
        note (nth (.data message) 1)
        velocity (nth (.data message) 2)]
    (js/console.log (str command note velocity))))

  (defn checkmidi []
    (-> (.requestMIDIAccess js/navigator)
      (.then #(onMIDISuccess %))
      (.catch #(onMIDIFailure))
      (.finally #(js/console.log "cleanup"))))

I'm not sure the .catch will work as I'm not sure how to get .requestMIDIAccess to fail.
```

Comment: Can you add your clojurescript code? Maybe you can try adding it like this `(.onmidimessage input (fn [& args] (println "in onmiddimessage, args:" args))`.

Comment: I should have included the cljs! I'm just a bit embarrassed about it. I'll add it to the original post...

Comment: It seems like I have to iterate over the inputs, but I'm not sure how to access them, and, due to immutability, it seems like it won't really do anything the browser would be able to access.

Comment: Haha. Code looks fine! One thing I would change is to use [sequential destructuring](https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring#_sequential_destructuring) instead of `nth`: `(let [[command note velocity] (.data message)] ...)`.

Comment: Thank you for this... I'll definitely try to make that better shortly, as soon as I get the main problem worked out. For now, I just swapped in a js/alert to the getMIDISuccess function to rule out the code in this function as a problem while I try to get the browser to recognize messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `set!`.

```
(defn getMIDIMessage [message]
  ...)

(defn onMIDISuccess [midiAccess]
  (-> midiAccess
      .-inputs
      (.forEach (fn [input key]
                  (set! input -onmidimessage getMIDIMessage)))))
```

Comment: I didn't know you could drill down to the values function like this, or to use array-seq! It's still not working, but I'm getting closer. I'm wondering if the midiAccess passed into onMIDISuccess is a copy of the thing on whose onmidimessage property I need to add the event listener. I'm also unclear on how to check if the midiAccess object has the function set correctly. Hitting a MIDI key isn't producing results, and I tried various attempts at console logging the property. Hmm.

Comment: In troubleshooting this, I realized I might be able to to try something like:
(-> (.requestMIDIAccess js/navigator)
    (.then #(.. midiAccess -inputs (values)))
for which I got an 'Cannot read property 'inputs' of undefined' error... is this even a sane approach? I also tried
(-> (.requestMIDIAccess js/navigator)
    (.then #(.. midiAccess -inputs))) which also produced an 'undefined' error.

Comment: I assumed values would return an array which it apparantly does not. I fixed the example so it just uses JS interop which should work.

Comment: You have no idea how exciting it was to see this work! Which is to say... it works! And thank you so very much! I was pretty discouraged by the time you helped. This is an important thing to learn for me, as this is a more complicated (for me) case of JS interop that I'll likely come across again.